# Camel 3.5 MongoDB component and findById with a simple String _id field

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

I'm using Camel 3.5.

https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mongodb-component.html#_query_operations

I'm trying retrieve one document from a MongoDb collection but the _id field is an UUID String and i cannot convert it to an ObjectId.

Here is an sample document :

```
{
    "_id" : "7cc141cd-9353-41ab-bc55-a9ab6ffe83ea",
    "street" : "2 rue Etienne Marcel",
}

from("direct:findById")
    .to("mongodb:myDb?database=flights&collection=tickets&operation=findById")
    .to("mock:resultFindById");
```

Tried this and it works, thx to @LucaBurgazzoli

```
exchange.getMessage().setBody(document.getString("_id"));
```

Comment: I've never tested it but the documentation states that "the incoming object can be anything that has an equivalent to a Bson type", did you try to set the body to an UUID ?

Comment: not sure if it helps, but here in this test we use a simple string: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-mongodb/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/mongodb/MongoDbFindOperationTest.java#L279

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli it works with an simple String thx